# Ionic navigation tab in header

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing, angularjs-routing, ionic-framework

Hey i've got a question about ionic navigation,

The main navigation of my application is in the footer, but i want to add an information tab to the header, I also want this tab to have it's own view so i set it up as seen below

```
 <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable nav-title-slide-ios7">
  <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon icon  ion-ios7-arrow-back">
    Back
  </ion-nav-back-button>
  <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
    <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top">

    <!-- Info Tab -->
    <ion-nav-view>
      <ion-tab title="Info" icon="icon ion ion-android-information" href="#/info/informatie">
        <ion-nav-view name="info-informatie"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>
     </ion-tabs>
    </ion-nav-view>


  </ion-nav-buttons>
</ion-nav-bar>
```

And I configured the Angular routing to an abstract class like this,

```
.state('info', {
  url: "/info",
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
})

    .state('info.informatie', {
        url: '/informatie',
        views: { 
            'info-informatie': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/info-informatie.html',
                controller: 'InfoCtrl'
            }
        }
    })
```

Now as far as i can tell this should do the trick, but the problems are that the 
tab doesn't show in the header, and also when i hardlink to the route it's stays on the same page without any kind of error...

i've made the templates, and configured the controllers.

I'm new with Angular as well as Ionic so it might be something quite easy but i can't figure it out.. i've read the manuals and the docs.

!!IMPORTANT NOTICE 
When i change the view to another one like

```
.state('info.informatie', {
        url: '/informatie',
        views: { 
            'TAB-OMGEVING': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/info-informatie.html',
                controller: 'InfoCtrl'
            }
        }
```

it works, but the active state is placed on another tab and the history stack traces back to that tab which is not what I intend to do and i would rather do it right from the start then build an app with cheap fixes and wrong use of codes.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you throw the header in your main view using ng-include, or are you looking for a breadcrumb type solution?

Comment: I have the header in my main view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few points, Im new to this too but hope Im of some help.

1. I think your code should be in the nav-bar segment, nav-view should be left empty as its the place where your html populates
2. use ui-sref instead of href..like `<a ui-sref='info.informatie'>something</a>`or alternatively use a button to employe ui-sref as well.
3. because u use info.something, naturally your parent or base state is info state.

Comment: haha thanks, this is a pretty old post so I already fixed this. if you understand the basics, angular learns really fast.

Comment: So please @SjoerdDeWit, If you fixed it please post the solution too. Thanks

Comment: yes, i somehow fixed it. could you describe what you want as answer? the code i use for my headerbar? @simonaAdriani

Comment: just searching how to put the tabs in the header, but I solved it adding a class 'tabs-top' in the tabs buttons container, the <ion-tabs ..> one

Comment: anyone found the answer yet. Plz post it how.