# Ionic / Angular ui-router -a href's returning wrong URL/content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mobile, angular-ui, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic tab menu which shows 4 items (the code below and codepen just have 2 items for clarity) and a "more" item which leads to further menu choices displayed as a list in an ion-content. It uses the Angular ui-router. I have two possibly connected issues.

**Issue 1:** at first the app appears to be working correctly but as you start to navigate around a few links (generally after visiting "more", the tabs will start to return incorrect URLS. For example:

Stating at News > Contact > More > Sports > Contacts > News > More - **breaks here,** I see Contacts content instead of More content.

I've add a console.log into each controller and in Chrome dev tools console, I can see that each tab click seems to lunch an extra event, e.g. clicking news tab means 'news' appears twice in the console. In addition, in the nav example above, the console shows that the contacts controller was launched when I clicked More.

*So to summarise, after some clicks around the app, the href targets seem to be sending me to the wrong place, like as if one had edited the code while it is running.*

**Issue 2:** Up until the point where the nav breaks as described above, the back button works correctly for pages launched from the tabs, but for the pages launched from the "more" page (ie from the list) there is no back button.

Sorry for all these beginner questions!

Codepen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hBpfa

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    </head>
  <body ng-app="schoolApp"  animation="slide-left-right-ios7">

    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable nav-title-slide-ios7 bar-positive">
      <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon icon  ion-ios7-arrow-back">
        Back
      </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>

    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

  <script id="tabs.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top">

    <ion-tab title="News" icon="icon ion-ios7-paper-outline SS-tab-icon" href="#/tab/news">
      <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

    <ion-tab title="Contact" icon="icon ion-ios7-telephone SS-tab-icon" href="#/tab/contact">
      <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

    <ion-tab title="More" icon="icon ion-navicon-round SS-tab-icon" href="#/tab/more">
      <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

  </ion-tabs>
  </script>

  <script id="more_tab_contents.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-view title="{{title}}">
    <ion-content class="has-header padding">

      <div class="list">
        <a nav-clear class="item item-icon-left" href="#tab/info">
          <i class="icon ion-ios7-information SS-tab-icon"></i>
          Information
        </a>
        <a nav-clear class="item item-icon-left" href="#tab/pictures">
          <i class="icon ion-camera SS-tab-icon"></i>
          Pictures
        </a>
        <a nav-clear class="item item-icon-left" href="#tab/sport">
          <i class="icon ion-ios7-football-outline SS-tab-icon"></i>
          Sports
        </a>
      </div>
    </ion-content>

  </ion-view>
  </script>

  <script id="inside.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view title="{{title}}">
      <ion-content class="has-header padding">
           <div class="SS_inside_content">
              <h1>{{title}}</h1>

              <ol>
              <li>In faucibus condimentum libero, vel iaculis nibh tristique ac. Nunc vitae urna felis. Praesent lectus ligula, vulputate id dolor at, porttitor pretium nulla. </li>
             <li>In faucibus condimentum libero, vel iaculis nibh tristique ac. Nunc vitae urna felis. Praesent lectus ligula, vulputate id dolor at, porttitor pretium nulla. </li>
             <li>In faucibus condimentum libero, vel iaculis nibh tristique ac. Nunc vitae urna felis. Praesent lectus ligula, vulputate id dolor at, porttitor pretium nulla. </li>
              <li>In faucibus condimentum libero, vel iaculis nibh tristique ac. Nunc vitae urna felis. Praesent lectus ligula, vulputate id dolor at, porttitor pretium nulla. </li>
             <li>In faucibus condimentum libero, vel iaculis nibh tristique ac. Nunc vitae urna felis. Praesent lectus ligula, vulputate id dolor at, porttitor pretium nulla. </li>
             <li>In faucibus condimentum libero, vel iaculis nibh tristique ac. Nunc vitae urna felis. Praesent lectus ligula, vulputate id dolor at, porttitor pretium nulla. </li>
              <li>In faucibus condimentum libero, vel iaculis nibh tristique ac. Nunc vitae urna felis. Praesent lectus ligula, vulputate id dolor at, porttitor pretium nulla. </li>
               </ol>
         </div>
     </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </script>

  <script id="" type="text/ng-template">
  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

App.js:

```
var schoolApp = angular.module('schoolApp', ['ionic'])



schoolApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider


   // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
    .state('tab', {
      url: "/tab",
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: "tabs.html"
    })

   .state('tab.news', {
      url: '/news',
      templateUrl: 'inside.html',
      controller: 'newsCtrl'
    })


   .state('tab.contact', {
      url: '/contact',
      templateUrl: 'inside.html',
      controller: 'contactCtrl'
    })



 .state('tab.info', {
      url: '/info',
      templateUrl: 'inside.html',
      controller: 'infoCtrl'
    })


.state('tab.pictures', {
      url: '/pictures',
      templateUrl: 'inside.html',
      controller: 'picturesCtrl'
    })

.state('tab.sport', {
      url: '/sport',
      templateUrl: 'inside.html',
      controller: 'sportCtrl'
    })


.state('tab.more', {
      url: '/more',
      templateUrl: 'more_tab_contents.html',
      controller: 'moreCtrl'
    })

  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/news');

});



schoolApp.controller('infoCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.title="Information";
  console.log ( 'info' );
})



schoolApp.controller('newsCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.title="Latest News";
  console.log ( 'news' );
})



schoolApp.controller('contactCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.title="Contacts";
  console.log ( 'contact' );
})



schoolApp.controller('picturesCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.title="Pictures";
  console.log ( 'pics' );
})
schoolApp.controller('sportCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.title="Sports";
  console.log ( 'sport' );
})

schoolApp.controller('moreCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.title="Further content choices";
  console.log ( 'more' );
});
```

**Update**

Further to discussions with @SjoerdDeWit and looking at the Ionic codepen examples, I have reverted to using named views, which I had done before. However before I was loading my "more" content into the tab view for News  - now I'm loading everything from the more page, and the pages it links to, into the named view for that tab - I think this is the way Ionic intend it to be done. So, as you click/tap "more" you get extra menu choices, the choose them and all the time you are still within the more tab, it is still active. Is this the way it should be?

One thing I notice. if I go to 'more', then 'sport' (within more) - then go to one of the other tabs, then back to more, I get sport, then tap more again and get the more menu options.

A log on each state controller shows (for a different sequence than above but same idea):

```
news named_views.js:96 (Launch of app)
contact named_views.js:100
more named_views.js:104
more > pics named_views.js:114
news named_views.js:96
more > pics named_views.js:114 FIRST TAP OF MORE - REVISIT IT
more named_views.js:104 TAP IT AGAIN
```

Revised index.html - just updates shown

```
  <script id="tabs.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top">

    <ion-tab title="News" icon="icon ion-ios7-paper-outline SS-tab-icon" ui-sref="tab.news">
        <ion-nav-view name="news-tab"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

    <ion-tab title="Contact" icon="icon ion-ios7-telephone SS-tab-icon" ui-sref="tab.contact">
      <ion-nav-view name="contact-tab"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

    <ion-tab title="More" icon="icon ion-navicon-round SS-tab-icon" ui-sref="tab.more">
      <ion-nav-view name="more-tab"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

  </ion-tabs>
  </script>

  <script id="more_tab_contents.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-view title="{{title}}">
    <ion-content class="has-header padding">

      <div class="list">
        <a nav-clear class="item item-icon-left" ui-sref="tab.info">
          <i class="icon ion-ios7-information SS-tab-icon"></i>
          Information ui-sref
        </a>
        <a nav-clear class="item item-icon-left" ui-sref="tab.pictures">
          <i class="icon ion-camera SS-tab-icon"></i>
          Pictures
        </a>
        <a nav-clear class="item item-icon-left" ui-sref="tab.sport">
          <i class="icon ion-ios7-football-outline SS-tab-icon"></i>
          Sports
        </a>
      </div>
    </ion-content>

  </ion-view>
  </script>
```

Revised javascript:

```
var schoolApp = angular.module('schoolApp', ['ionic'])



schoolApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

   // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
    .state('tab', {
      url: "/tab",
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: "tabs.html"
    })


   .state('tab.news', {
      url: '/news',
      views: {
        'news-tab': {
          templateUrl: 'inside.html',
          controller: 'newsCtrl'
        }
      }
    })



   .state('tab.contact', {
      url: '/contact',
      views: {
        'contact-tab': {
          templateUrl: 'inside.html',
          controller: 'contactCtrl'
        }
      }
    })



   .state('tab.more', {
      url: '/more',
      views: {
        'more-tab': {
          templateUrl: 'more_tab_contents.html',
          controller: 'moreCtrl'
        }
      }
    })




 .state('tab.info', {
      url: '/info',
      views: {
        'more-tab': {
          templateUrl: 'inside.html',
          controller: 'infoCtrl'
         }
      }
    })



.state('tab.pictures', {
      url: '/pictures',
      views: {
        'more-tab': {
          templateUrl: 'inside.html',
          controller: 'picturesCtrl'
         }
      }
    })

.state('tab.sport', {
      url: '/sport',
      views: {
        'more-tab': {
          templateUrl: 'inside.html',
          controller: 'sportCtrl'
         }
      }
    });


  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/news');

}); // end config




schoolApp.controller('newsCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.title="Latest news";
  console.log('news');
})
schoolApp.controller('contactCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.title="Contact us";
  console.log('contact');
})
schoolApp.controller('moreCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.title="More (tabs overflow)";
  console.log('more');
})

schoolApp.controller('infoCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.title="Information";
  console.log('more > info');
})

schoolApp.controller('picturesCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.title="pictures";
  console.log('more > pics');
})
schoolApp.controller('sportCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.title="Sports";
  console.log('more > sports');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved these issues (and in doing so have other questions but that will be for another time)

Issue 1 - click/tap tab and getting incorrect content. Fixed with changes made above below the **Update**

Issue 2 - back nav not appearing in some places, see this:

```
<a nav-clear class="item item-icon-left" href="#tab/info">
  <i class="icon ion-ios7-information SS-tab-icon"></i>
  Information
</a>
```

**nav-clear** was stopping back button, as it should - I must have copied 'n' pasted it from some sample code

Comment: I read through it and i had some sort of the same solution.. if i really want something outside of it i load it in the index.html view where normally the tabs are loaded into this is usefull because it also makes an option for excluding the tabs in some pages like a detail page with a back button and footer actions don't really need tabs, they can just click back to get to the tabs

Comment: Hi, I do not really understand what you mean. Do you mean in the case of, for example, a settings widget? I think I would use a modal or popover there? Anyway I'm making progress now with the project - many thanks for your help!

Comment: no, i've a detail page which has to be accesible throughout my app so i created a custom view for it outside the tabs so i can always link too it and back, i don't want to put the same popup for over 10times in my app

Answer (score 5):

Angular and Ionic use the UI-Router. Instead of using an href attribute you should use the ui-sref followed by the state u want to go too. i've remade your footer tabs with the correct way of routing in Ionic and Angular

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top">

<ion-tab title="News" icon="icon ion-ios7-paper-outline SS-tab-icon" ui-sref="tab.news">
  <ion-nav-view name="news"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>

<ion-tab title="Contact" icon="icon ion-ios7-telephone SS-tab-icon" ui-sref="tab.contact">
  <ion-nav-view name="contact"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>

<ion-tab title="More" icon="icon ion-navicon-round SS-tab-icon" ui-sref="tab.more">
  <ion-nav-view name="more"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>
```

You do not specify the views. so when you click on news > contact contact is loaded into the news ionview that is located in the ion-tabs if u set it up like this with the names and change your app.js to this you should be oke, although if i'm not mistaken the back button doesn't show up anymore cause the link is present in the tabs

```
 .state('tab.news', {
      url: '/news',
      views: {
                'news': 
            { 
                    templateUrl: 'inside.html',
                    controller: 'newsCtrl', 
            }
        }
    })


   .state('tab.contact', {
      url: '/contact',
      views: {
                'contact': 
            { 
                    templateUrl: 'inside.html',
                    controller: 'contactCtrl',  
            }
      }
    })



 .state('tab.more', {
      url: '/more',
      views: {
                'more': 
            { 
                    templateUrl: 'inside.html',
                    controller: 'infoCtrl', 
            }
      }
```

})

Comment: Thank you for your help. I replaced all links with state refs but still the same problem exists.

Comment: you did not set up your views correct so it loaded in the wrong     ion-nav-view Both the ion tabs section and the app.js has been edited @user602088

Comment: Hi, I actually had done it like that before, using the Ionic examples as a basis. But my problem with that was when you clicked (tapped) on "more" - this displayed a page with links (within a named 'more' view). In my routing I could not get it to work for these "more" pages (ie not from clicking a tab but clicking a link in the more page) without re-using one of the existing tab views. Thus one of the tabs was getting incorrect content. I'll try to put up a codepan

Comment: I had the exact same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24203470/ionic-navigation-tab-in-header

Comment: Here is a codepen of what I had before with named views http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ghJvF - if you click around enough (going into more) you will eventually see that the News tab gets populated with the wrong content

Comment: I viewed your previous question - it seems you did not get an answer?

Comment: no i didn't not many ionic/angular users... but i'm 2 months past that and learned alot about it, btw is this the desired result ? http://codepen.io/sjerd/pen/bBazq

Comment: Hi, I think you just changed my href to ui-srefs in the more page? I still got it to fail. I'm looking at this example now to try to understand it as it seems to do what i want http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/odqCz. PS site says we should move to chat?